# DNS/Name servers updated for others but not for me

Tags: dns

I updated my DNS to point to other nameservers a few days ago, and it seems like it's working perfectly well for everyone except for me. When I visit it, I get redirected to the company where I bought it from's parked domain-page.

I've visited it with multiple proxies and the domain works fine there, too.

What can I do so it works for me as well?

Comment: Someone may be able to help better if you give details of your setup -- browser(s), operating system, network infrastructure. For instance, under Linuxes it could be revealing to check the output of `dig <domain>` or `dnstrace <domain>`.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to [clear](https://support.opendns.com/hc/en-us/articles/227988627-Clearing-the-DNS-Cache-on-Computers-and-Web-Browsers) operating system and/or browser names cache.